# How to display an image in WPF from a referenced project?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core, .net-4.8

I have two projects
This is the main WPF project configuration where I want to display the image from a referenced project. The main project is a .NET Core WPF with the name CH07.RemoteBinaryResourceDemo.csproj and the referenced project .NET Framework Class Library CH07.ResourceLibrary.csproj
Can anyone please help

This is my CH07.RemoteBinaryResourceDemo.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\CH07.ResourceLibrary\CH07.ResourceLibrary.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have another project the referenced project .NET Framework Class Library, with the file structure

```
+CH07.ResourceLibrary
+--+Images
   +--+image1.jpg
```

In my CH07.RemoteBinaryResourceDemo/MainWindow.xaml

```
<Image Width="150"
               Margin="8"
               Source="pack://application:,,,/CH07.ResourceLibrary;component/Images/image1.jpg"/>
```

This doesn't work. I've tried everything I know to build, clean build, rebuild doesn't work.

Comment: The Build Action of the image file must be Resource. The library should be a WPF class library.

Comment: I did that and it still didn't display, I even tried content

Comment: Is `CH07.ResourceLibrary` the correct assembly name? The library project `CH07.ResourceLibrary.csproj` should generate an assemby named `CH07.ResourceLibrary.dll`. Is it a WPF library?

Comment: Yes that the correct assembly name and yes it's a WPF library

Comment: The only suggestion I can make is that you compile CH07.ResourceLibrary, remove your project reference and add a reference to the compiled assembly. As Clemens says, ensure that you have set the Build Action to Resource for your images. Leave the Copy to Output Directory blank as with all the other properties for the image. If you willing to post your project I would be happy to review it

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename the Folder: Change the folder name from `Images` to `images` (all lowercase) in your `CH07.ResourceLibrary` project.
2. Update the Pack URI: In your `CH07.RemoteBinaryResourceDemo/MainWindow.xaml`, update the Source attribute of your Image tag to use the lowercase path. It should look like this:

```
<Image Width="150" Margin="8" 
Source="pack://application:,,,/CH07.ResourceLibrary;component/images/image1.jpg"/>
```

3. Rebuild the Projects: After making these changes, rebuild both the `CH07.ResourceLibrary` and `CH07.RemoteBinaryResourceDemo` projects.